# Find the zeros in integer multiplication

Tags: factorial, natural-numbers

How many zeros at the end of multiplication of natural numbers from 10 to 75?

What i did: 
$$\left[\frac{75}{5^1}\right]+\left[\frac{75}{5^2}\right]=18=\text{Zeros at the end of 75!}$$
$$\left[\frac{10}{5^1}\right]=2=\text{Zeros at the end of 10!}$$
$$18-2=16$$

But correct answer is $17$.

Comment: I get $14$ multiples of $5$ and three of $25$. There must be enough twos dividing it to ensure that $10^{17}$ is a factor.

Comment: You get the result of $75!/{10!}$, not $75!/\color{red}{9!}$, while the latter is the product from 10 thru 75.

Comment: @xbh  why i should get $9!$   ?

Comment: @SerifYaohim I have explained above.

Comment: @xbh thank you a lot dude)))

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication of the numbers 10 to 75 is the same as $10*11*12...73*74*75$ which can be represented as:
$$x=\frac{75!}{9!}$$
Sterlings approximations states:
$$n!\approx\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$
so we know that:
$$x=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi *75}\left(\frac{75}{e}\right)^{75}}{\sqrt{2\pi*9}\left(\frac{9}{e}\right)^9}=\sqrt{\frac{75}{9}}*75^{75}*9^9*e^{66}\approx2.89*10^{140}*10^{9}*10^{29}=2.89*10^{178}$$
This is my best approximation of the answer, I cant think of a way that nobody else has shown of working out the zeros on the end.

Comment: The actual answer is: $68,367,341,301,243,932,131,686,720,449,167,861,719,924,613,884,948,530,747,894,330,116,445,774,574,440,221,035,724,800,000,000,000,000,000$ and there are 17 on the end